# Laravel app name is not showing as wanted

Tags: laravel

I have a website and it's domain name is

> doiniqbazar.com

I developed this site using laravel framework.When i send a link "doiniqbazar.com" to my friends in facebook messenger it show the applicaation name "Laravel".

[image]

> I changed both .env file and config/app.php file but still not
>   working.

Is there any procedure to change laravel app name??

Comment: Have you changed the value in `config/app.php`? `'name' => 'Whatever'`. (Woops, you said you are, sorry) Beyond that, it may be using the HTML `title` of the page, so you'd have to update that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This display has nothing necessarily to do with your app name.

It'll grab this from the `<title>` or `og:title` meta tags in your HTML. (You *may* be outputting the `APP_NAME` value here.)

Facebook has [a handy tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) for debugging this sort of sharing metadata issue.

*Note:* It may also be cached. Facebook's debugger reported the same `Laravel` title in your title tag; when I did a re-scrape it picked up your new title. Apple will likely do the same after a while; I'm not aware of a re-scrape API on their end.

See also: [Best Practices for Link Previews in Messages](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2444/_index.html)

Comment: i changed all title tag but still it showed "Laravel"

Comment: @MostafijurRahman As I noted in my answer, it may be cached for a period of time.

Comment: Problem solved @ceejayoz.It is cashed issue as you earlier said.